# Using a SQL wildcard ignoring non-alphanumeric characters in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two-column table:

```
product        name
cars           ["bmw", "mazda", "ford", "dodge"]
fruit          ["lemon", "orange", "lime", "apple"]
```

I'm using a wildcard to search the product's name column. My question is, is there a way to search a column only by alphanumeric characters and ignore the " and [ ]?

For example, if the user searched bmw the query would be: LIKE '%bmw%' and it would return cars, however if the user searches bmw" and the query is: `LIKE '%bmw"%` or they enter dodge"] and the query would be `LIKE '%dodge"]%"` it would want it to not return any results.

My current query:

```
SELECT product, name FROM `test1` WHERE name LIKE '%bmw%'
```

It doesn't need to be a wildcard basically, I am after the query only providing the product if the exact name is used but because of the format of the name column it's giving me problems.

Comment: Where is dodge coming from if the user just searches for bmw? Did you mistype something there?

Comment: Don't put lists in a column. Normalize your table structure.

Comment: If you really want to use this structure, use the JSON datatype, and then use `JSON_SEARCH()`

Comment: It sounds like you just need to remove the quotes when you're processing the search input from the user, before putting it into the query.

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays.  What is the _type_ of the `name` column?  Is it text?

Comment: JSON_SEARCH() was what led me to the answer, providing the corresponding product and disregarding any quotations etc. Thank you. https://database.guide/json_search-find-the-path-to-a-string-in-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clean the data before it's being added to the query.

e.g.You can use regex to replace unwanted characters / only allow certain characters in a text.
Then you can add that "cleaned" data as a parameter to that query.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, it is always better to include `code snippets` in support of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested `JSON_SEARCH()` is what I needed to achieve my desired outcome.

See: https://database.guide/json_search-find-the-path-to-a-string-in-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Specifically Example 5 – Wildcards.